# Where do I find the "send to" Compressed (Zipped) folder

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, compression

I am trying to compress a Zip archive to an external hard drive on my PC. Space is limited on the system so I can't compress it locally. I have access to WinZip but can't download or install any third-party software due to account restrictions. Does anyone know a method to do so?

Comment: In my experience it is always the current directory.

Comment: Using the Windows archive utility, yes, but luckily our friend Robert has WinZip available.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a copy of what you want to zip on the external hard drive if you have enough space on there, then zip it in place, then delete the uncompressed version

Comment: If he already has WinZip then you can just create the archive in said location, thus removing a step and some time.

Comment: @DarkWolffe yeah that would be better. I hadn't noticed the comment saying he had winzip

Comment: I want the one that compress and uncompress. Will WinZip do that ?

Comment: @PROBERT yes winzip should do that. If Winzip is installed you can I think you can create an empty winzip archive in the external hard disk, and drag and drop files into it (you may be able to do this with Windows' built in archive utility as well actually: go to the hard drive, Rightclick > New > Compressed File. If that's available you're good to drag and drop onto it

Answer (score 0):

Windows creates the `*.zip` archive wherever the source contents are located. If you want to create it somewhere else, you should look into a program such as [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/).

Comment: Yes, but problem is my office is under US Government and we can't download anything from the internet. We do have WinZip and the compressed from Windows 7.

Comment: Using WinZip, you can create the archive in a different location by doing thus:
1. Find the folder or file you want to compress.
2. Right-click on said folder or file and select the WinZip menu item.
3. Click `Add to Zip file...`
4. In the first input box, click the `New...` button and choose the directory and filename you wish to save to.
5. Click `Add` and watch the magic happen.